# Reported Speech - sentence with two verbs

Tags: grammar, indirect-speech

> "Did it hurt when you touched the wire?", the doctor asked.

Let's say that we want to put the above sentence in reported speech.

Would it be

> The doctor asked if it had hurt when I touched the wire.

or

> The doctor asked if it had hurt when I had touched the wire.

I always find such sentences quite confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While both sentences are grammatically correct, the first sounds much more natural.

If you wanted to use the wording of the second sentence, you could instead use:
"The doctor asked if it hurt when I had touched the wire."